# Android :How to stretch video in android device with the device height-width?

Tags: android, video, android-layout, device, android-videoview

In my app, I am going to display the Video.
But the video height and width is smaller then then device Screen height width.
So what should i have to do if i want to stretch the Video height and width that set to device height and width.

I am using VideoView to load video. And i have set its property as fill_parent for both height and width. but even doing that i am not able to get stretch video to the device height and Width.

main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/playingRelativeLayout" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#FFFFFF">
        <VideoView
            android:id="@+id/myVideoView"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            />
```

So please help me for that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android does not support the resizing of videos, you may want to look into a Third Party library that you can utilize. By default android does not have this, If I recall correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the Reply. In My application I am taking video file from the sdcard. But before that i am copying file from assets folder to sdcard. So is there any way to convert the video file that fit to the device screen during copy to sdcard? May be it will solve my issue. Any anyother idea you have ?